# Unit Testing a service with $http and $q using mocha, chai and sinon

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, browserify, sinon, chai

I have this function and need test it using mocha, chai and sinon.

This is [my code](http://plnkr.co/edit/UaYER1Vet196gNhy0uc3):

service-wiki-pelis.js

```
'use strict'

var WikiService = function($http,$q){

    return {
        getMovies: getMovies
    }

    function getMovies() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.jsonp('/url/movies')
            .success(function(data,status,headers,config) {
                deferred.resolve({
                    results: data.results
                });
            }).error(function(msg,code) {
                msg = msg || 'Request failed: ';
                deferred.reject(msg);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    }

}

module.exports = WikiService;
```

service-wiki-pelis_test.js

```
var chai = require('chai'),
    should = chai.should(),
    sinon = require('sinon');

describe('Wiki Pelis service',function(){

    'use strict';

    var service, WikiPelisService = require('./service-wiki-pelis');

    var $http = {jsonp:function(url){
            return {
                success: function () {
                },
                error: function () {
                }
            }
        }},
        $q = {};

    beforeEach(function(done){
        service = new WikiPelisService($http,$q);
        done();
    });

    it('Should have a function named "JSONP"',function(){
        service.jsonp.should.be.instanceof(function);
    });
});
```

So far I've this small test, but really it doesn't work, but with it you can see my test environment.

Those two files are part of an angular app, but should be possible to test these alone, without angular mocks or something like that.

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what would happen if that site went down in the future!

Comment: @dcodesmith I've added a sample of my test, I hope you can help me.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using jasmine so I could create a jsfiddle for the solution. Find comments in line.

You'll need angular-mocks file. You can still use chai for your assertions.

```
describe('Service: ', function () {
    var service,
        $httpBackend,
        url = '/url/movies',
        returnedPromise,
        result;

    //load the angular app module
    beforeEach(function () {
        module('MyApp');
    });
    // inject your service and $httpBackend from angular-mocks.js
    beforeEach(inject(function (MyService, _$httpBackend_) {
        service = MyService;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        // invoke your getMovies method
        returnedPromise = service.getMovies();
    }));

    //make sure no expectations where missed
    afterEach(function () {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    it('should make a successful API call and return a list of movies', function () {
        var expectedResult = {
            results: []
        };
        $httpBackend.whenJSONP(url).respond({
            results: []
        });
        returnedPromise.then(function (response) {
            result = response;
        });
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(result).toEqual(expectedResult);
    });

    it('should make a unsuccessful API call and return an error', function () {
        var expectedResult = 'Request failed: ';
        $httpBackend.whenJSONP(url).respond(401);
        returnedPromise.then(function (response) {}, function (msg) {
            result = msg;
        });
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(result).toEqual(expectedResult);
    });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/f6objsqy/)**

Comment: Thanks in advance, but really I don't want do use "angular-mocks", using that way exists a lot of tutorials, and really is the easier way, I want use sinonjs to mock the dependencies.